SwiftData model child, not updating forEach (@Observable not working)
I am transitioning a perfectly functional CoreData to SwiftData, and everything was going well... until I hit a problem when updating the properties of an array.
I tried to use the trick of wrapping in an @Observable class that I saw on this question, without luck.
So, here we have the parent, who is rendering a view of a Project, containing Time objects.
import SwiftUI
import SwiftData


struct ProjectRowView: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) var modelContext
    @Bindable var project: Project
    @Query private var times: [Time]
    private var timesByProjects: [Time] {
        times.filter { $0.project?.id == project.id}
     }
    
    @State private var zeroDurationExists: Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text(project.name)
                    .foregroundStyle(project.hasRunningTimers ? .red : .black)
                TimeDisplay(project: project)
            }
            if !project.hasRunningTimers {
                Image(systemName: "play")
                    .onTapGesture {
                        addTime(to: project)
                        updateZeroDurationExists()
                    }
            }
            if project.hasRunningTimers {
                Image(systemName: "pause")
                    .onTapGesture {
                        calculateDurationAndPause(for: project)
                        updateZeroDurationExists()
                    }
                }
            }
        .onAppear{
            updateZeroDurationExists()
        }
        .onChange(of: times) {
            updateZeroDurationExists()
        }
    }

    func updateZeroDurationExists() {
        zeroDurationExists = timesByProjects.contains { $0.duration == 0 }
        }
    func addTime(to project: Project) {
        let time = Time(name: "", duration: 0, startDate: .now, isRunning: true)
        project.times?.append(time)      
        do {
           try modelContext.save()
        } catch {
           print(error)
        }
        
    }
    func calculateDurationAndPause(for project: Project) {
        let times = timesByProjects
        if let zeroDurationTime = times.first(where: { $0.duration == 0 }) {
            if zeroDurationTime.startDate != nil {
                zeroDurationTime.duration = Int64(Date().timeIntervalSince(zeroDurationTime.startDate ?? Date.now))
                zeroDurationTime.isRunning = false
                zeroDurationTime.project = project
                do {
                   try modelContext.save()
                } catch {
                   print(error)
                }   
            }
        }
        do {
           try modelContext.save()
            
        } catch {
           print(error)
        }
    }
}


And then we have the TimeDisplay.swift that will display the Times objects.
import SwiftUI
import SwiftData

@Observable
class ProjectModel {
    var project: Project
    init(project: Project) {
        self.project = project
    }
}


struct TimeDisplay: View {
    var project: ProjectModel
    init(project: Project) {
            let projectModel = ProjectModel(project: project)
            self.project = projectModel
        }
    
    var body: some View{
        ForEach(project.project.times ?? [], id:\.self) { time in
            Text("Time Duration: \(time.duration)")
                .font(.caption)
                .foregroundStyle(time.isRunning ? .red : .black)
        }
    }
}

ProjectView
import SwiftUI
import SwiftData

struct ProjectView: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
    @Query(sort: \Project.creationDate) var projects: [Project]
    @Binding var path: [Project]
    
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(projects, id: \.self) {project in
                ProjectRowView(project: project)
            }
            .onDelete(perform: deleteProject)
        }
        .navigationTitle("Projects")
        .navigationDestination(for: Project.self) { project in
            EditProjectView(project: project)
        }
        .toolbar {
            Button("Add Project", systemImage: "plus") {
                let project = Project(name: " ", creationDate: .now)
                modelContext.insert(project)
                path = [project]
                do {
                    try modelContext.save()
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }
            }
            Button("Delete all", systemImage: "minus") {
                do {
                    try modelContext.delete(model: Project.self)
                    try modelContext.delete(model: Time.self)
                    try modelContext.save()
                } catch {
                    print("Failed to clear "    )
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
    func deleteProject(at indexSet: IndexSet) {
        for index in indexSet.sorted(by: >) {
            guard index < projects.count else { continue }
            modelContext.delete(projects[index])
        }
        do {
            try modelContext.save()
        } catch {
            print("Error saving context after deletion: \(error)")
        }
    }
}


The Project Model
@Model
class Project: Hashable {
    var name: String = "Untitled"
    var creationDate: Date = Date.now
    var times: [Time]? = [Time]()

    var hasRunningTimers: Bool {
        return unwrappedTimes.contains { $0.isRunning }
    }
    
    init(name: String, creationDate: Date) {
        self.name = name
        self.creationDate = creationDate
    }
}

The Time Model
import Foundation
import SwiftData

@Model
class Time: Hashable  {
    var name: String = "Untitle Time"
    var duration: Int64 = 0
    var isRunning: Bool = false
    var startDate: Date? = Date.now
    var project: Project?
    
    
    init(name: String, duration: Int64, startDate: Date, project: Project? = nil, isRunning: Bool) {
        self.name = name
        self.duration = duration
        self.startDate = startDate
        self.isRunning = isRunning
        self.project = project
    }

}

Creating the time object is refreshing the view. But modifying the duration property when pausing the timer is not triggering a re-render of the forEach.
I would be happy to try any suggestions, as my workaround for now has been to do a deep copy of the time object, removing the original and adding the copy back to force the re-render. Very ugly!
Thanks in advance ☀️
[Edited to simplify]

I’m having the same issue, would love to see some solutions

It would be helpful to have a simplified reproducible example for testing.  Observable will trigger updates if the project changes, but I am not sure if it will trigger updates to properties of Project, if Project is not itself also observable.  I would try a few things like maybe using Bindable to the ProjectModel object, or an onChange(of: project.project.times) to update some state in TimeDisplay, but can't really test any of this without a complete working example of your setup.

its best you check for the zero durations when you save rather than when you query. By the time body is called all the data should be ready and you shouldn't need onAppear or onChange to fix it up.

Although you don't show the code for it, I conclude that Project is a @Observable class.
It is not clear why you are using @Bindable var project: Project in ProjectRowView,
since you are not using it that view nor in TimeDisplay as a binding.
Use just a var project: Project.

Thanks for your answers, trying to wrap my head around the possible solutions.
So far, I have tried what you suggest, as much as possible, but it didn't work. The Time list is still updated when adding time (adding elements to the array), but not when changing the property. Adding more details to the questions,
The entire project is visible on https://github.com/jamesmandelbaum/SyncTime/tree/main/SyncTime

Note,  @Model class already conforms to Hashable, no need to do it again.
Also @Model class conforms to Identifiable, that means you should do
ForEach(projects) not ForEach(projects, id: \.self), similarly for the others loops, do not use id: \.self.
In Project var hasRunningTimers, what is unwrappedTimes, where does this come from?
Why use ProjectModel when you already have @Model class Project which also conforms to Observable.
Try removing it and use only the Project you get from SwiftData.
